Freeradius 3.0 not logging client access requests and results to radius.log
I'm running Freeradius 3.0 on Ubuntu, and I am trying to get the Access-Request, Access-Challenge, and Access-Accept/Reject logs I can see in real-time to get pushed to the radius.log file but they never appear there.
In the radiusd.conf file, I have logdir=/var/log/freeradius. In the log{ section of that file, I have the settings destination = files, and file = ${logdir}/radius.log. I have the setting auth = yes, I have also (even though it's redundant) set auth_accept = yes and auth_reject = yes.
But when I authenticate a client with this Freeradius, I don't see the access messages I can see in real-time get logged in radius.log. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?
